# Javascript change an value of a JSON key from String to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string

I have an service that some time return data structure like this

```
params:value;
```

and then sometime return

```
params:[value1, value2];
```

I want to change if value is String (first case), then delete it and make an empty params:[]. How can I aechive it?

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: JSON is JavaScript object notation... treat it like Javascript in Javascript....

Comment: `o.params = typeof o.params === "string" ? [] : o.params;`

Comment: @nicael I checked if it is a string by instanceof and then assign it as new array but nothing happen. Edit: Nvm, I wrote the wrong params:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) JSON you can use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator  to see if value is string and if it is change it to empty array `[]`.

```js
var data = {
  params: 'value'
}

if(typeof data.params === 'string') data.params = [];
console.log(data);
```